# opencv: how to convert all black pixels to transparent and save it to png file

Tags: python, opencv

The image is below, I want all black pixels to be transparent and save it to png file.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it fast and vectorised like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image as Numpy array in BGR order
na = cv2.imread('I5jKW.png')

# Make a True/False mask of pixels whose BGR values sum to more than zero
alpha = np.sum(na, axis=-1) > 0

# Convert True/False to 0/255 and change type to "uint8" to match "na"
alpha = np.uint8(alpha * 255)

# Stack new alpha layer with existing image to go from BGR to BGRA, i.e. 3 channels to 4 channels
res = np.dstack((na, alpha))

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png', res)
```

[image]

Notes:

1 You could equally use `cv2.merge()` in place of `np.dstack()` and it is probably faster.

2 You could equally use PIL/Pillow in place of the OpenCV functions to read/save images.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way to do that in Python/OpenCV/Numpy.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('girl_on_black.png')

# threshold on black to make a mask
color = (0,0,0)
mask = np.where((img==color).all(axis=2), 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

# put mask into alpha channel
result = img.copy()
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:, :, 3] = mask

# save resulting masked image
cv2.imwrite('girl_on_black_transparent.png', result)

# display result, though it won't show transparency
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: @Bin Chen If my answer was helpful, please give it an up-vote.

Comment: The first one works much better. This does not actually make the black transparent it just makes a mask of the black areas

Comment: @JackNorthrup.  Not true. `result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)` `result[:, :, 3] = mask` first converts the image to 4 channels and then puts the mask into the 4th (alpha channel).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce):

> PNG images with an alpha channel can be saved using this function. To
> do this, create 8-bit (or 16-bit) 4-channel image BGRA, where the
> alpha channel goes last. Fully transparent pixels should have alpha
> set to 0, fully opaque pixels should have alpha set to 255/65535 (see
> the code sample below).

A transparent image comes with an extra channel which we call **alpha** channel and denote with `BGRA` in opencv. All you need to do is that creating a mask image which is in the format of `BGRA`. Then detect all the black pixels in the image and for those black pixels assign **alpha** channel of mask image to 0.

**Note:** With opencv `imshow` or others you will not be able to see a transparent image because opencv can not display alpha channel. So you need to write it with `imwrite` in the **png format**.

**Note:** Making transparent any pixel means that assigning its alpha channel to 0.

Here is the output of what I mean:

[image]

Since I am not familiar with python, I coded the steps in C++. Sorry for that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>


int main()
{


    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("/ur/input/img.png",cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

    cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(img.cols,img.rows),CV_8UC4);

    cv::namedWindow("Input",0);
    cv::namedWindow("Output",0);


    for(int i=0; i<mask.cols; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<mask.rows; j++)
        {

            if(img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(i,j))[0] == 0 &&
                    img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(i,j))[1] == 0 &&
                    img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(i,j))[2] == 0)
            {
                mask.at<cv::Vec4b>(cv::Point(i,j))[0] = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(i,j))[0];
                mask.at<cv::Vec4b>(cv::Point(i,j))[1] = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(i,j))[1];
                mask.at<cv::Vec4b>(cv::Point(i,j))[2] = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(i,j))[2];
                mask.at<cv::Vec4b>(cv::Point(i,j))[3] = 0;
            }
            else {
                mask.at<cv::Vec4b>(cv::Point(i,j))[0] = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(i,j))[0];
                mask.at<cv::Vec4b>(cv::Point(i,j))[1] = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(i,j))[1];
                mask.at<cv::Vec4b>(cv::Point(i,j))[2] = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(i,j))[2];
                mask.at<cv::Vec4b>(cv::Point(i,j))[3] = 255;
            }

        }
    }




    cv::imshow("Input",img);
    cv::imshow("Output",mask);


    cv::imwrite("/ur/writing/dir/transparent.png",mask);
    cv::waitKey(0);



    return 0;
}
```