# Pythion openCV- How to copy all non black pixels to new image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to make a program that makes panoramic images. I am able to match and warp images but my method of actually stitching them together is slow and I'm sure there is a better way. Currently, I'm just looping through each pixel and checking if it's zero and set it if not. This takes a while since my images are 6000x6000 and I need to do this many times. I want to put every pixel with color from img2 on top of the image saved in img1.

I am trying to stitch this image:

[image: photo]

on to this image:

[image: photo]

The written code is:

```
while i < x:
    if showall or showsome:
        if i % (int(x/4)-1) == 0:
            print(str(xa) + '%...')
            xa = xa + 25
    if cv.countNonZero(img2[i]) > 0:
        while j < y:
            if(img2[i][j].any() > 0):
                img1[i][j] = img2[i][j]           
            j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
    j = js
```

This is what my stitching code looks like right now. I know its very inefficient. Any ideas?

Comment: may I suggest that you work through the introductions of numpy and opencv? they show how to handle entire images at once. that may involve "masks" and indexing using masks.

Comment: Have a look here and you can see one (vectorised) way of making a mask of black/non-black pixels https://stackoverflow.com/a/70224145/2836621